# Flutter, How can I change page programmaticly in PaginatedDataTable?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, paginateddatatable

I have a PaginatedDataTable and searchbar, It's work great but when I Searched my DataTable is not going to first page. When I click first Page its going first page and my new filtered list is showing. How can I change page programmaticly in dataTable?

This my PaginatedDataTable

```
    PaginatedDataTable paginatedDataTable = PaginatedDataTable(
    actions: [
      AnimatedSearchBar(
          width: 300,
          textController: _searchController,
          onSuffixTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _searchController.text = "";
            });
          }),
      widget.showDialog == null
          ? SizedBox()
          : AddUpdateButton(
              buttonType: ButtonTypes.add,
              onPressed: widget.showDialog,
            )
    ],
    initialFirstRowIndex: firstRowIndex,
    source: dts, 
    rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
    header: Text(
      widget.title,
      style: CustomTextStyle.mblackBoldTextStyle,
    ),
    sortColumnIndex: _sortColumnIndex,
    sortAscending: _sortAscending,
    availableRowsPerPage: [
      _defaultRowsPerPage,
      _defaultRowsPerPage * 2,
      _defaultRowsPerPage * 5,
      _defaultRowsPerPage * 10
    ],
    showCheckboxColumn: false,
    dataRowHeight: widget.dataRowHeight,
    showFirstLastButtons: true,
    onRowsPerPageChanged: (r) {
      setState(() {
        _rowsPerPage = r;
      });
    },
    columns: widget.headerList.map((e) {
      return DataColumn(
          label: Text(e.name.toUpperCase()),
          onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
            if (e.sort) {
              return _sort(
                  (T d) => d.getProp(e.propName), columnIndex, ascending);
            }
          });
    }).toList(),
  );
```

Comment: try `PaginatedDataTableState.pageTo()` method

Comment: thank you I solved same way @pskink

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I create a key

```
final key = new GlobalKey<PaginatedDataTableState>();
```

Give key PaginatedDataTable

```
 PaginatedDataTable(
        key: key
        ...)
```

and ı use this function

```
key.currentState.pageTo(0);
```

you can look this question for use key state :
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895273/how-to-use-globalkey-to-maintain-widgets-states-when-changing-parents/62226807#62226807)